# can xpath be use this way?

Tags: java, arrays, xpath, arraylist

```
System.out.println("The U value: " + u);
Statement stmt3 = null;
ResultSet srs3 = null;
List28 = new ArrayList<String>();
stmt3 = conn.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT [USERS_SYS_ID],[GROUPS_SYS_ID] as groupID FROM [USERS_GROUPS] WHERE [USERS_SYS_ID] = " + (u + 1);
srs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(query);
while (srs3.next()) {
    List28.add(srs3.getString("groupID"));
}
System.out.println("Group ID: " + List28);

String z = "0";
z = null;
z = ("T_GROUP_" + List28.get(0));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=z")).click();

System.out.println("Group ID: " + driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=z]")));
```

Given that the value of `u` is 2 and `List28` give a return 2.

Is it possible to run click on the xpath like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=z")).click();
```

Comment: i tried it out but i am not able to run the code.. can i know where are the mistake and what should i do to correct it? thanks!

Comment: `.//*[@id=z` is not a valid XPath

Comment: yeah i notice it also.. it is not a valid xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using the String.format()

```
String xpathExpression = String.format(".//*[@id='%s']", z);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).click();
```

or simply

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='"+z+"']")).click();
```